# Example of integrable time-dependent one degree-of-freedom Hamiltonian system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory, integrable-systems, complex-systems

It is known that any time-independent one degree-of-freedom Hamiltonian system is necessarily integrable, because the Hamiltonian itself is a first integral.

However, if the Hamiltonian is time-dependent, or more specifically, a periodic function of time, then it can be chaotic.

So, can anyone give an **integrable** example? Presumable, chaotic examples are the majority.

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search gives the following integrable time-dependent 1D Hamiltonian:
$$H(x,t)=\frac{p^2}{2}+\Omega(t) \frac{q^2}{2},$$
which is classically integrable for any well-behaved $\Omega(t)$. See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.6034) for the details. More examples can be found in the same paper.